# Комбинированные псевдоклассы CSS

Tags: html, css

Есть контейнер с блоками. `.big_banners` и `.medium_banners` - разделы. Элементы раздела - вложенные внутрь разделов `div`-ы.

Хотел написать правило, что каждый элемент в разделе должен иметь отступ сверху на 10px, не считая первый элемент раздела. Экспериментировал в псевдоклассами `:not`, `:first-child`, и в один момент я понял, как можно решить дилемму, но псевдокласс отказывается работать в придуманной мной связке, а именно `.banners-content div:not(.medium_banners):first-child {}`. По другому пытался переписать код, убил час, не пришел к выходу.
Правило действует не до конца правильно, оно задаёт класс первому элементу, но игнорирует `:not(.medium_banners)`. Почему, неизвестно.

Правило должно обнулять отступ для каждого первого элемента в разделе, но не должно трогать элементы в разделе `.medium_banners`

(В рамках демонстрации сделал отступ 40px)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.banners-content {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 956px;
  background: #ddd;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
/* .big_banners div,
.medium_banners div {
  margin-top: 10px;
} */
.banners-content div:not(.medium_banners) {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.banners-content div:not(.medium_banners):first-child {
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.big_banners div:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.medium_banners {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
}
a[href="#"] img{
background: brown;
}
```

```html
 <div class="banners-content">
  <div class="big_banners">
    <div>
      <a href="#" target="_blank">
        <img style="width:100%; height:120px" src="./assets/images/big_banner_placeholder.png" alt="" />
      </a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="#" target="_blank">
        <img style="width:100%; height:60px"
          src="./assets/images/medium_banner_placeholder.png"
          alt=""
        />
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="medium_banners">
    <div>
      <a href="#" target="_blank">
        <img style="width:100%; height:60px"
          src="./assets/images/small_banner_placeholder.png"
          alt=""
        />
      </a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="#" target="_blank">
        <img style="width:100%; height:60px"
          src="./assets/images/small_banner_placeholder.png"
          alt=""
        />
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: что в твоем случае является разделом, а что элементом раздела?

Comment: По описанию непонятно, кому ты хочешь поставить 10px, а кому - 40px

Comment: @Grundy, разделы - medium_banners, big_banners. Элемент раздела - внутрь вложенные div-ы
Правило должно обнулять отступ для каждого первого элемента в разделе, но не должно трогать элементы в разделе medium_banners.

Comment: пока выглядит так, будто тебе нужен стиль для `.big_banners` и нет нужды что-то придумывать с `:not` и подобным

Comment: @Grundy, повторюсь, нужен стиль для первых элементов разделов, но при этом не должен трогать элементы в разделе `.medium_banners`

Comment: Попытаюсь разъяснить, какое правило я пытался создать.
`.banners-content div:not(.medium_banners):first-child {}`: 
Для div-блоков внутри `.banners-content`, не считая (:not) `.medium_banners`, первому элементу дать стиль {}
По сути, одно и тоже что `.banners-content div:first-child {}`, только стиль не должен применяться для `.medium_banners`

Comment: все равно непонятно, зачем так делать, если можно просто у `big_banners` поставить отступ и все.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вышло немного костыльно, но проблема была решена

```css
.banners-content {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 956px;
  background: #ddd;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.banners-content div:not(.medium_banners) {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.banners-content>div:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.banners-content div:first-child:not(.medium_banners)div {
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.big_banners div:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.banners-content>div:first-child:not(.big_banners)>div {
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.medium_banners {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
}

a[href="#"] img{
background: brown;
}
```

```html
 <div class="banners-content">
  <div class="big_banners">
    <div>
      <a href="#" target="_blank">
        <img style="width:100%; height:120px" src="./assets/images/big_banner_placeholder.png" alt="" />
      </a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="#" target="_blank">
        <img style="width:100%; height:60px"
          src="./assets/images/medium_banner_placeholder.png"
          alt=""
        />
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="medium_banners">
    <div>
      <a href="#" target="_blank">
        <img style="width:100%; height:60px"
          src="./assets/images/small_banner_placeholder.png"
          alt=""
        />
      </a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="#" target="_blank">
        <img style="width:100%; height:60px"
          src="./assets/images/small_banner_placeholder.png"
          alt=""
        />
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Спустя долгое количество времени пришел к выводу, что лучший способ - применить gap для flex-контейнера элементов, а не margin задавать для каждого